# reload page once hidden value has been set

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hidden

How do I make a page reload once a hidden input field has been set?

This is my field:

```
<input id="fieldID" type="hidden" value="">
```

Thanks for your help.

Here is my intire script including the proposed answer.

It currently doesn't work but I have a feeling that more due to a missing parenthesis or something like that.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#notification').fadeOut('fast');
        }, 3000);


        $('#fieldID').on('change', function(){
            window.location.reload();
        });


        $('.iframe-btn').fancybox({
        'width' : 880,
        'height'    : 570,
        'type'  : 'iframe',
        'autoScale'   : false
        });
        $('#download-button').on('click', function() {
          ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'download-buttons');      
        });
        $('.toggle').click(function(){
          var _this=$(this);
          $('#'+_this.data('ref')).toggle(200);
          var i=_this.find('i');
          if (i.hasClass('icon-plus')) {
            i.removeClass('icon-plus');
            i.addClass('icon-minus');
          }else{
            i.removeClass('icon-minus');
            i.addClass('icon-plus');
          }
        });
    });

        tinymce.init({
                language : 'sv_SE',
                selector: "textarea",theme: "modern",
                plugins: [
                    "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                    "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager",
                    "link",
                ],
                link_list: [  
                    <?                          
                        $sql="select * from pages order by position";
                        $rs=mysql_query($sql, $conn);

                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
                            $tmp_header=$row["header"];
                            $tmp_id=$row["id"];
                            if($row["position"] == "0") {
                                echo("{title: '".$tmp_header."', value: '?&page_id=1'},");
                            }
                            else if($row["position"] !== "-1") {
                                echo("{title: '".$tmp_header."', value: '?&page_id=".$tmp_id."'},");    
                            }
                        }
                        $sql="select * from pages order by position";
                        $rs=mysql_query($sql, $conn);

                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
                            $tmp_header=$row["header"];
                            $tmp_id=$row["id"];
                            if($row["position"] == "-1") {
                                echo("{title: '".$tmp_header."', value: '?&page_id=".$tmp_id."'},");
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    ],

               toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image responsivefilemanager table",
               image_advtab: false, 
               menubar: false,

               external_filemanager_path:"js/filemanager/",
               filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
               external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/website/js/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
            });

</script>
```

Comment: `$("#fieldID").val("foobar"); reloadPage();`

Comment: @KevinB he wanted a listener for a change, not HOW to change. popnoodles provided a good solution for this.

Comment: @bvx89 except that there's nothing built-in that will trigger said change event other than triggering it yourself. It's a hidden input, the user can't interact with it.

Comment: If he has to trigger it himself, he might as well skip changing the value at all and just reload.

Comment: @KevinB I'm aware of that, I just expected that he/she knew that part since the question was only related to the change. And yes, it seems like a ridiculous thing to do.

Comment: I have the changing thing figured out I just needed the listener. 

Although now I have a messy script that I need to get under control.

Comment: KevinB has a valid point unless some other code elsewhere is triggering change, possibly being the common result of several different actions, which OP can take advantage of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to see why you would do this with a hidden input, but this is the code:

```
$('#fieldID').on('change', function(){
    window.location.reload(); // <-- there are several ways to swing this cat
});
```

You will find changing the value with JS doesn't trigger change.

```
$('#fieldID').val(123); // will not trigger change
$('#fieldID').val(123).trigger('change'); // will
```

But you could just reload then anyway, like KevinB suggested.

Comment: That looks like something that should work.

However, when itried to add it to my document i made the other part of my script unresponsive. 

Could you please advice.

Comment: What do you mean by unresponsive? I can't see a syntax error that would cause it to break. Do you know how to view your console to look for errors? (In Chrome F12 then click Console)

Answer (score 0):

When the contents are changed, reload the page:

```
$("#fieldID").change(function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

To fake a user input:

```
$("#fieldID").trigger("change");
```